# Is implicit character to be discarded from token list silently when TeX finds it useless?

Tags: xetex, tex-core

The source below compiles successfully

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\let\lbrace={ 
\let\rbrace=}

\def\hello#1{[Hello, #1!]}

\hello{Amy}

\hello\lbrace Bob

\def\hellol{\hello\lbrace}
\def\hellor{\rbrace}

\hellol David \hellor

\end{document}
```

with output as follows:

```
[Hello, Amy!]
[Hello, !]Bob
[Hello, !]David
```

Obviously, `Bob` and `David` aren't evaluated as arguments of macro `\Hello`, which sugguests that implicit characters `\lbrace` and `\rbrace` don't work as group, even though they have been let to begingroup `{` and endgroup `}` respectively. Moreover, note that `\hello\lbrace Bob` is not in balance in form since there is no `\rbrace` to match, but I confuse why it does work with no error, though the result differs from what I expect originally.

I think TeX absorbs control sequences like `\lbrace` and `\rbrace` into token list, and when TeX finds them useless, TeX discards them from list. Is that true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `\lbrace` and `\rbrace` in order to delimit the argument to a macro. But they work for grouping (which is a distinct concept from macro argument). There is no “discarding”.

If you do

```
\def\foo#1{X#1X}
```

and call

```
\foo\lbrace a\rbrace
```

TeX will take `\lbrace` as `#1` and will replace

```
X\lbrace Xa\rbrace
```

Here's a full plain TeX example, where I use `\bgroup` and `\egroup` that are defined in the format by

```
\let\bgroup={ \let\egroup=}
```

so they're the same as your `\lbrace` and `\rbrace` (by the way, you're so redefining existing macros).

```
\def\foo#1{X#1X}

\foo\bgroup a\egroup b

\foo\bgroup \it a\egroup b

\bye
```

[image]

You see that `\it` is confined to the group `\bgroup \it a\egroup` that is the result of macro expansion according to what I wrote at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I just wonder how TeX treats the token `\bgroup` following the macro `\foo`. In fact, TeX takes it as `\foo`'s argument. But now that we have `\let\bgroup={`, so why not TeX take it as an equivalent to `{`? In other words, Why can't  we use `\lgroup` and `\rgroup` in order to delimit the argument to a macro?

Comment: @wuxj Basically because Knuth decided this way.